# Why can't my Anaconda install of Python find some packages?

Tags: python, conda

For some reason, I seem unable to import certain modules in my macOS Anaconda install of Python.

```
$which python
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

I can use some packages (pandas loads fine, for example), but wget and pypdf2 cannot be found. I've removed and installed both again using the following commands:

```
$conda install -c conda-forge pypdf2
$conda install -c anaconda wget
```

They appear to be installed:

```
$conda list
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pypdf2                    1.26.0                   pypi_0    pypi
wget                      1.20.1               h051b688_0    anaconda
```

When importing, I get the following 'module not found' errors

```
>>>import wget
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wget'

>>>import pypdf2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypdf2'
```

Any ideas what's going on here and what else I can do to troubleshoot? Thank you.

Comment: As an aside, are you using the base environment for this?

Comment: I suggest we close this as a duplicate of [conda "No module named wget" after conda install wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58879866/conda-no-module-named-wget-after-conda-install-wget).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) is not a Python package. It is a command-line program used to download things from the internet. You can use it as `wget`on the command-line.

Your error with `pypdf2` occurs because you are not importing it properly. Use

```
import PyPDF2
```

as per [the examples](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/blob/master/Sample_Code).

Comment: There is a python package named wget, but I indeed installed the command line tool. Feeling very foolish. Thank you!